# Discord bot python Channel not defined

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

i was doing this

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    invitelinknew = await client.create_invite(destination = channel, xkcd = True, max_uses = 100)
    print(invitelinknew)
```

As you understand i want to create a link of the servers the bot in with the server name and id.
I have dont the server names with id but in this it says `channel is not defined`
how do i define channel?
Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `on_ready` isn't something that happens in a specific channel, so you'll have to tell your bot which channel you want to create the invite for.  You can use [`get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) with the id.

Comment: i did this but this NameError: name 'get_channel' is not defined how do i define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Client.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) method to get the `Channel` object using the `id`:

```
channel = client.get_channel("channel id")
```

This will return `None` if it can't find a channel with that id.